# Why Gulp Serve exiting without any error message after 'serve' task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gulp, babeljs

I recently migrated a gulp file based on gulp 3.x to 4.x by adding gulp.series for tasks and async functions for the task functions

But when I started gulp serve , it finishing the 'clean' and 'serve' task but exiting without starting the server and no messages shown

**Log:**

```
> videostream@2.0.0 start /root/VideoStream
> gulp serve

[01:47:05] Requiring external module babel-register
[01:47:05] Using gulpfile ~/VideoStream/gulpfile.babel.js
[01:47:05] Starting 'serve'...
[01:47:05] Starting 'clean'...
[01:47:05] Finished 'clean' after 5.31 ms
[01:47:05] Finished 'serve' after 6.8 ms

root@iZa2d90eklkjfyzkilci2vZ:~/VideoStream#
```

Look at the logs . After `Finished 'serve'` it simply exits to the console

There is no errors and no warning and even no logs of the ExpressJS server. It's weird

This is gulp file

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import gulpLoadPlugins from 'gulp-load-plugins';
import path from 'path';
import del from 'del';
import runSequence from 'run-sequence';

const plugins = gulpLoadPlugins();

const paths = {
  js: ['./**/*.js', '!dist/**', '!node_modules/**', '!coverage/**'],
  nonJs: ['./package.json', './.gitignore', './.env', './services/fet_firebase.json'],
  tests: './server/tests/*.js'
};

// Clean up dist and coverage directory
gulp.task('clean', (done) => {
  del.sync(['dist/**', 'dist/.*', 'coverage/**', '!dist', '!coverage']);
   done();
}
);

// Copy non-js files to dist
gulp.task('copy', (done) => {
  gulp.src(paths.nonJs)
    .pipe(plugins.newer('dist'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
  done();
}
);

// Compile ES6 to ES5 and copy to dist
gulp.task('babel', (done) => {
  gulp.src([...paths.js, '!gulpfile.babel.js'], { base: '.' })
    .pipe(plugins.newer('dist'))
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(plugins.babel())
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('.', {
      includeContent: false,
      sourceRoot(file) {
        return path.relative(file.path, __dirname);
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    done();
}
);


// Start server with restart on file changes
gulp.task('nodemon', gulp.series(['copy', 'babel']), () => {
  plugins.nodemon({
    script: path.join('dist', 'index.js'),
    ext: 'js',
    ignore: ['node_modules/**/*.js', 'dist/**/*.js'],
    tasks: ['copy', 'babel']
  });
done();
}
);

// gulp serve for development
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series(['clean']), (done) => {runSequence('nodemon'); done();});

// default task: clean dist, compile js files and copy non-js files.
gulp.task('default', gulp.series(['clean']), (done) => {
  runSequence(
    ['copy', 'babel']
  );
done();
});
```

Since I am new to nodejs , I cant figure it what's the issue \

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

As I understand in the documentation, the `gulp.task()` signature is `gulp.task([taskName], function)`. Thus, it does not expect the third argument. I believe you can fix it by refactoring like this (you'll also have to fix the `nodemon` task):

```
// gulp serve for development
gulp.task('serve', (done) => {
  gulp.series(['clean', 'nodemon']);
  done();
});
```

Additionally, it is not recommended, per the [documentation](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series), to register the tasks and pass them to `series()` as strings. Instead, do this:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const gulpLoadPlugins = require('gulp-load-plugins');
const del = require('delete');
const path = require('path');
const runSequence = require('run-sequence');

const plugins = gulpLoadPlugins();

const paths = {
  js: ['./**/*.js', '!dist/**', '!node_modules/**', '!coverage/**'],
  nonJs: ['./package.json', './.gitignore', './.env', './services/fet_firebase.json'],
  tests: './server/tests/*.js'
};

// Clean up dist and coverage directory
function clean(done) {
  del.sync(['dist/**', 'dist/.*', 'coverage/**', '!dist', '!coverage']);
  done();
}

// Copy non-js files to dist
function copy(done) {
  gulp.src(paths.nonJs)
    .pipe(plugins.newer('dist'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
  done();
}

// Compile ES6 to ES5 and copy to dist
function babel(done) {
  gulp.src([...paths.js, '!gulpfile.babel.js'], { base: '.' })
    .pipe(plugins.newer('dist'))
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(plugins.babel())
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('.', {
      includeContent: false,
      sourceRoot(file) {
        return path.relative(file.path, __dirname);
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
  done();
}

// Start server with restart on file changes
function nodemon(done) {
  gulp.series(copy, babel)
  plugins.nodemon({
    script: path.join('dist', 'index.js'),
    ext: 'js',
    ignore: ['node_modules/**/*.js', 'dist/**/*.js'],
    tasks: ['copy', 'babel']
  });
  done();
}

// gulp serve for development
function serve(done) {
  gulp.series(clean, nodemon);
  done();
}

exports.clean = clean;
exports.copy = copy;
exports.babel = babel;
exports.serve = serve;
// default task: clean dist, compile js files and copy non-js files.
exports.default = gulp.series(clean, copy, babel);
```

Comment: getting error : : SyntaxError: /root/VideoStream/gulpfile.babel.js: Unexpected token (64:9) .......

function default(done)

Comment: I thought that since default is a reserved keyword , So I changed default to defaultTask...

Comment: now i am getting an error :: - Task never defined: serve

Comment: I also added exports.default = defaultTask in the end of file . But still same error

Comment: I also ran gulp --tasks and it returned nothing

Comment: so I converted function serve to like this .... gulp.task('serve', (done) => {
  gulp.series(clean,nodemon);
  done();
});

Comment: Now ....!! , again the very same issue I mentioned in the question arising again

Comment: this is the edited file as suggesred by you .......     https://gist.github.com/TechRova/b15b5f8da957e4a4492650480b39b31b

Comment: But now only serve task is running .. No info about other tasks

Comment: Try exporting them as done in the [docs](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/creating-tasks), an example of which I added to the end of the answer

Comment: I also have not seen the `import ` syntax in any examples. Try refactoring and using the `require` syntax instead. I've updated my answer to reflect this syntax for your specific imports